# Make a list of items in similar pk DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["1-1", "mood", "1"],["1-1", "abc", "2"], ["1-2", "def", ""], ["1-2", "ghi", "3"], ["1-3", "jk", ""]], columns=["PK", "item", "factor"])
```

```
>>> print(df)
PK    item factor
1-1   mood "1"
1-1   abc  "2"
1-2   def  ""
1-2   ghi  "3"
1-3   jk   ""
```

and I want the output data frame to be like

```
PK   item    factor
1-1  mood    [1,2]
1-1  abc     [1,2]
1-2  def     [3]
1-2  ghi     [3]
1-3  jk      []
```

Comment: What's the logic behind?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) after convert to int with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df['factor']  = df['PK'].map(pd.to_numeric(df['factor'].replace('"','',regex=True),
                                           errors='coerce')
                                   .dropna()
                                   .astype(int)
                                   .groupby(df['PK']).apply(list))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    PK  item  factor
0  1-1  mood  [1, 2]
1  1-1   abc  [1, 2]
2  1-2   def     [3]
3  1-2   ghi     [3]
4  1-3    jk     NaN
```

Comment: This last element should be an empty list, as per OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `mapper` that will know how to bind your `PK` values towards the expected `factor` column:

```
mapper = df.groupby("PK")
           .factor
           .apply(list)
           .apply(lambda l: [int(e) for e in l if e])  # cast to int, keep if != ''
           .to_dict()

df.factor = df.PK.apply(mapper.get)
```

Where:

```
>>> print(mapper)

{'1-1': [1, 2], '1-2': [3], '1-3': []}
```

And now:

```
>>> print(df)

    PK  item  factor
0  1-1  mood  [1, 2]
1  1-1   abc  [1, 2]
2  1-2   def     [3]
3  1-2   ghi     [3]
4  1-3    jk      []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
df=df.set_index("PK")

df["factor"]=df["factor"].str.strip('"')

df["factor"]=df.loc[df["factor"].ne('')].groupby(level="PK")["factor"].agg(list)

df.loc[df["factor"].isna(), "factor"]=[[]]

df=df.reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```py
    PK  item  factor
0  1-1  mood  [1, 2]
1  1-1   abc  [1, 2]
2  1-2   def     [3]
3  1-2   ghi     [3]
4  1-3    jk      []
```